# Is it possible to embed an iframe container inside another element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is it possible to dynamically wrap an iframe container inside another container with jQuery?

going from < iframe > to  < iframe >

The iframe is already on the page.  Just figuring out how to wrap it when either the DOM is ready or when the Window is ready.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. With jQuery you can wrap up an iframe with a div for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PBaTu/